# What sort of algorithm describes loose hanging wire physics?

Tags: algorithm

And can anyone point me in the direction to the best/simplest one.

I've been searching on google but no keyword I use returns programming results.

Comment: Do you mean something other than finite element analysis?

Comment: You might get a better answer over at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The keyword might be "Rope physics"

Comment: @YzmirRamirez This question is not appropriate for cstheory; it's not a research-level question in theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 4):

You could search for `Rope Physics`. There's an example tutorial [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rope_physics/17006/). Depending on the material of your wires, you can change the parameters. Verlet Integration lends itself well to rope physics as well and there's a very nice tutorial on Verlet Integration [here](http://www.gamasutra.com/resource_guide/20030121/jacobson_01.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

Idealized hanging chain forms a [catenary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) which is graph of function y=cosh(x).

Answer (score 2):

You can model it using a string of point masses attached by small rods. If you want the wire to be stretchable, then you could use springs instead of rods.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall from my engineering days, the general phrase is "[elastica](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Elastica.html)". You can find interesting models around, for things like the [Reverse spaghetti problem](http://scitation.aip.org/getabs/servlet/GetabsServlet?prog=normal&id=JAMCAV000054000001000147000001&idtype=cvips&gifs=yes&ref=no).